# Cannot read property 'vehicle_full' of undefined

Tags: javascript, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk

When I am loading my app I am getting this js exception. Not sure why!

> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'vehicle_full'
>   of undefined at ActionCreators.js:?

```
export function loadPairDataActionCreator(address, refresh, topPartner, bottomPartner) {
  return dispatch => fetch(address, returnHeaders())
    .then(res => checkLogout(res))
    .then(
      data => {
        // Change primary key from SHA to cName
        if (data) {
          let nd = [];
          for (let p in data) {
            const pair = data[p];
            let tmp = {};
            const pair_ids = Object.keys(pair);
            for (let pi of pair_ids) {
              tmp[pair[pi].vehicle_full] = pair[pi];
            }
            nd.push(tmp);
          }
          data = nd;
          store.dispatch(currentPairs(data));
          let vehicles = store.getState().vehicles,
            keys = Object.keys(vehicles);

          for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            const pair = data[i];

            // pair ids
            const [vehicle1, vehicle2] = Object.keys(pair);

            // Add pairedWith field to each truck in the pair

            store.dispatch(
              addPairedVehicleActionCreator(
                pair[vehicle2].vehicle_full, //<--- error here
                vehicle1
              ))
            store.dispatch(
              addPairedVehicleActionCreator(
                pair[vehicle1].vehicle_full,
                vehicle2
              ))
          }
          store.dispatch(pairingComplete(true))
        }
      },
      err => dispatch({
        type: 'LOAD_PAIR_DATA_FAILURE',
        err
      })
    )
    .then(
      () => {
        if (refresh === "unpair") {
          store.dispatch(changePageModeActionCreator({
            mode: "READY_TO_UNPAIR",
            rowIdentifier: store.getState().pageMode.rowIdentifier
          }));
        } else if (refresh === "pair") {
          store.dispatch(changePageModeActionCreator({
            mode: "READY_TO_PAIR",
            rowIdentifier: topPartner,
            rowIdentifierBottom: bottomPartner
          }));

        }
      }
    )
    .then(
      () => {
        store.dispatch(removePairedVehicleActionCreator(topPartner)),
          store.dispatch(removePairedVehicleActionCreator(bottomPartner))
      }
    )
}
```

Comment: there is 3 places where you use `vehicle_full` can you point us which line is throwing this exception?

Comment: Here i am getting exception                                                           
             store.dispatch(
                  addPairedVehicleActionCreator(
                    pair[vehicle2].vehicle_full,
                    vehicle1
                  ))

Comment: What shape has the `data` object ?